# Параграф в JSX файле

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Как решить проблему с переносом строки в JSX файле в ReactJS? Тег `pre` не работает, а `br` выглядит ужасно и неэффективно.

```
<div className={classes.poem}>
  <h3 className={classes.title}>{props.title}</h3>
  <pre>
    {props.poem}
    Գիշերն ամբողջ հիվանդ, խելագար, <br/>
    Ես երազեցի արեւի մասին: <br/>
    Շուրջս ո՛չ մի ձայն ու շշուկ չկար – <br/>
    Գունատ էր շուրջս՝ գիշեր ու լուսին: <br/>
    Ես երազեցի արեւի ոսկին, <br/>
    Տենչացի նրա հրաշքը խնդուն՝ <br/>
    Ուզեցի սիրել շշուկն իմաստուն՝ <br/>
    Արեւանման, արնավառ խոսքի, – <br/>
    Բայց շուրջս այնպես գունատ էր, տկար – <br/>
    Խոսքեր չկային, ու արեւ չկար … <br/>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: ну этот вопрос не именно по `JSX`, я так полагаю. а ответ очевиден - либо оставляйте `<br>` и исправляйте деффекты стилями, либо оборачивайте каждую строку в блоки и тоже стилизируйте

Comment: Так в обычной верстке тег pre - решение, а именно в jsx не работает,,,, вариант с br или строки в блоках - кошмар, если стих может иметь более 100 строк

Comment: а что именно внутри `<pre>` не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Шаблонные литералы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) позволяют использовать многострочные строки, которые сохраняют начальные/конечные пробелы и новые строки. Шаблонные литералы должны быть заключены в обратные кавычки. Плюс ко всему в JSX нужно этот шаблонный литерал заключить в фигурные скобки. Для наглядности приведет пример ниже:

```jsx
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
        return (
          <pre>{`
            Hello,   
            World.
          `}</pre>
        )
    }
}
```

Пример, согласно прикрепленному блоку кода из вопроса:

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
        return (
          <pre>{`
                    Գիշերն ամբողջ հիվանդ, խելագար,
                    Ես երազեցի արեւի մասին:
                    Շուրջս ո՛չ մի ձայն ու շշուկ չկար –
                    Գունատ էր շուրջս՝ գիշեր ու լուսին:
                    Ես երազեցի արեւի ոսկին,
                    Տենչացի նրա հրաշքը խնդուն՝
                    Ուզեցի սիրել շշուկն իմաստուն՝
                    Արեւանման, արնավառ խոսքի, –
                    Բայց շուրջս այնպես գունատ էր, տկար –
                    Խոսքեր չկային, ու արեւ չկար …
          `}</pre>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />, 
  document.getElementById('pre')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!-- The content rendered into this tag should match the content below. -->
<div id="pre"></div>
```

Ссылка на источник: [Formatting code with  tag in React and JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864001/5275890)

Comment: Вот круто. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ЕрвандС-ян - вы можете отметить ответ правильным, если он решает вашу задачу. Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом, галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ [отмечен как решение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Также будет полезно: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: ого.. вот это действительно мощно. лайкнул ответ