# Как конвертировать содержимое файла.txt для отображения внутри компонента

Tags: html, reactjs

Подскажите как обычно решается следующая проблема:
есть содержимое текстового файла, как нужно эти данные конвертировать, чтобы они корректно отобразились внутри компонента ?

```
fetch(fileNameOnServer)  //  http://localhost:3000/filedata12.txt
        .then(response => response.text())    // res.json()
        .then(
          (result) => {
              content = result // <-- Тут нужно выполнить конвертацию ???            
          })
// -----------------------------------------------------
return (
      <div className='FilesRightContent'>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
```

Дело в том, что браузер этот файл отображает корректно. А у меня внутри компонента - каша (не соблюдается перевод строки ...

Comment: на крайний случай посмотрите [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098290/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84-%d0%b2-jsx-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5/1098473#comment1892734_1098473)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положи текст в тег `<pre>` или примени соответсвующий css

```
white-space: pre;
```